# How to check if type can be converted to another type in C#

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have two types `sourceType` and `targetType` and I need to write a method in C#, which checks if values of `sourceType` can be assigned to a variable of `targetType`. The signature of the function is `MatchResultTypeAndExpectedType(Type sourceType, Type targetType)`.

The inheritance is covered by [IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Type.IsAssignableFrom%29;k%28SolutionItemsProject%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework). In the case of convertible types I thought to use [CanConvertFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92580th5.aspx), but, for example, if both types are numerical, then it always returns `false`.
A test, which I performed:

```
TypeConverter typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Decimal));
Console.WriteLine("Int16 to Decimal - " + typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(Int16)));
Console.WriteLine("UInt16 to Decimal - " + typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(UInt16)));

typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(long));
Console.WriteLine("UInt16 to Int64 - " + typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(uint)));

typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Double));
Console.WriteLine("UInt16 to Double - " + typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(UInt16)));

typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(String));
Console.WriteLine("UInt16 to String - " + typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(UInt16)));
```

The result is:

```
Int16 to Decimal - False
UInt16 to Decimal - False
UInt16 to Int64 - False
UInt16 to Double - False
UInt16 to String - False
```

**[EDIT]** So my question:
Is there a way in .NET to check whether a value of a given type can be assigned to a variable of another type without knowing values, e.g., whether implicit conversion will succeed? More specific requirements for implementation of `MatchResultTypeAndExpectedType(Type sourceType, Type targetType)`:

1. Source and target types are not known at compile time, since their assemblies are loaded later.
2. No values or objects can be provided as input.
3. No objects of the types can be created in the implementation, since it is not allowed by the rest of the system. Values of value types can be created.
4. Only implicit conversion has to be checked.

It is known whether `sourceType` is value type. So the signature of the method can be like `MatchResultTypeAndExpectedType(Type sourceType, Boolean isSourceValueType, Type targetType)`

One way is to implement [Implicit Numeric Conversions Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but it will not cover other conversions or user defined conversions.

Comment: You should more strictly define "converted or assigned to another numeric type". You can, of course, convert/assign a long to an int, but you will lose data because an int64 has 4 more bytes than an int32.

Comment: Do you also care about any [implicit/explicit user defined conversion operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that may be implemented?

Comment: It would be great to cover implicit user defined conversion operators.

Answer (score 10):

The problem about implicit/explicit conversions is that they're resolved at compile time. So there is (as far as I know) no simple runtime check. *However*, the `dynamic` implementation *will* pick them out and invoke them at runtime. You can (however ugly) create a class which will attempt to perform the conversion, catch the exception if it fails, and report whether or not it passed:

```
public class TypeConverterChecker<TFrom, TTo>
{
    public bool CanConvert { get; private set; }

    public TypeConverterChecker(TFrom from)
    {
        try
        {
            TTo to = (TTo)(dynamic)from;
            CanConvert = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            CanConvert = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Given some classes like:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static implicit operator Bar(Foo foo)
    {
        return new Bar();
    }

    public static implicit operator Foo(Bar bar)
    {
        return new Foo();
    }
}

public class Bar
{
}

public class Nope
{

}
```

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine((new TypeConverterChecker<Foo, Bar>(new Foo())).CanConvert); //True
Console.WriteLine((new TypeConverterChecker<Bar, Foo>(new Bar())).CanConvert); //True
Console.WriteLine((new TypeConverterChecker<Foo, Nope>(new Foo())).CanConvert); //False
```

And with the types you tested:

```
Console.WriteLine((new TypeConverterChecker<Int16, Decimal>(0)).CanConvert); //True
Console.WriteLine((new TypeConverterChecker<UInt16, Decimal>(0)).CanConvert); //True
Console.WriteLine((new TypeConverterChecker<UInt16, Int64>(0)).CanConvert); //True
Console.WriteLine((new TypeConverterChecker<UInt16, Double>(0)).CanConvert); //True
Console.WriteLine((new TypeConverterChecker<UInt16, String>(0)).CanConvert); //False
```

Now I can imagine this can be modified to be more efficient (cache the result statically so subsequent lookups for the same `TFrom, TTo` combination don't have to attempt the conversion, for value-types ignore the need for an input instance to cast (just use `default(TFrom)`) and so on, but it should give you a start. It should be noted that you should *not* pass in `null` for `TFrom from` as all `null` conversions will pass (unless it's to a value-type)

You can also add a second `try/catch` to attempt using the [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx) method and see if the types have defined `IConvertable` implementations that can be leveraged. (you may want to store this as a separate boolean flag so you know which type of conversion you need to perform later)

EDIT: If you don't know the types at compile time, you can take advantage of a bit of reflection to still leverage the conversion checker:

```
public static class TypeConverterChecker
{
    public static bool Check(Type fromType, Type toType, object fromObject)
    {
        Type converterType = typeof(TypeConverterChecker<,>).MakeGenericType(fromType, toType);
        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(converterType, fromObject);
        return (bool)converterType.GetProperty("CanConvert").GetGetMethod().Invoke(instance, null);
    }
}
```

Your usage might be like:

```
object unknownObject = new Foo();
Type targetType = typeof(Bar);
Type sourceType = unknownObject.GetType();
Console.WriteLine(TypeConverterChecker.Check(sourceType, targetType, unknownObject));

targetType = typeof(Nope);
Console.WriteLine(TypeConverterChecker.Check(sourceType, targetType, unknownObject));
```

Comment: In my case the source and target types are available as variables, since new types can be loaded during runtime of the application.

Comment: @k_rus: so you do not know `TFrom` or `TTo` at compile time? That's ok, you can evaluate their types and use generics to create the generic method at runtime. I will update my answer.

Comment: This is a clever approach, actually.

Comment: @Chris Sinclair: thanks. I am already looking how I can do this approach in my application.

Comment: It is not necessary to provide from object to `TypeConverterChecker`, since default can be used, e.g., `TFrom from = default(TFrom)`.

Comment: @k_rus: if `TFrom` is a reference-type (i.e. a `class`, not a `struct`) then `default(TFrom)` will be `null`. Any `null` conversion from one reference-type to another reference-type will pass thus giving you false-positives. Using `default(TFrom)` will _only_ provide valid results if `TFrom` is a `struct`. I already noted this caveat in my answer. Feel free to make a `class StructTypeConverterChecker<T> where T : struct` which does this though! :)

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a solution, which partially satisfy my requirements. It is based on the answer from @ChrisSinclair, but does not require to provide an object of `sourceType`. 
The implementation is:

```
    public static Boolean MatchResultTypeAndExpectedType(Type sourceType, Type targetType) {
        if (sourceType.IsValueType)
            return Check(sourceType, targetType);
        else
            return targetType.IsAssignableFrom(sourceType);
    }

    public static bool Check(Type fromType, Type toType) {
        Type converterType = typeof(TypeConverterChecker<,>).MakeGenericType(fromType, toType);
        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(converterType);
        return (bool)converterType.GetProperty("CanConvert").GetGetMethod().Invoke(instance, null);
    }

    public class TypeConverterChecker<TFrom, TTo> {
        public bool CanConvert { get; private set; }

        public TypeConverterChecker() {
            TFrom from = default(TFrom);
            if (from == null)
                if (typeof(TFrom).Equals(typeof(String)))
                    from = (TFrom)(dynamic)"";
                else
                    from = (TFrom)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TFrom));
            try {
                TTo to = (dynamic)from;
                CanConvert = true;
            } catch {
                CanConvert = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

There are two problems with the solution:

1. It does not check if there are implicit conversions for non-value types (e.g., user defined). Since `IsAssignableFrom` is used, only inheritance is covered for non-value types.
2. It does not cover value types, which has null value as default and does not have default constructors, except `String`. `String` is explicitly covered.